# Scrolling list with iScroll in the middle of window

Tags: css, html, jquery-mobile, iscroll4

I have a list in my page,I want the list be scrollble, only the list without all the rest of the page...I using `iScroll` js file

this is my code:

```
<div id="ds">
            <div id="rtrt">
    <ul data-role="listview" id="a1"                
<li>
<a href="#">1</a>
</li>
<li>
<a href="#">2</a>
</li>
<li>
<a href="#">3</a>
</li>
.
.
.
.
         </ul>
            </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
 var myScroll;
        function loaded() {
                myScroll = new iScroll('rtrt');
            }

document.addEventListener('touchmove', function (e) { e.preventDefault(); }, false);
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () { setTimeout(loaded, 200); }, false);
</script>
```

But the scroll is over the list on all the window,so i scrolling over all the screen, How can I scroll only the list in the middle of the screen (in mobile).

Any ideas?

Comment: Why not an iframe? It would do exactly what are you looking for... http://docs.webplatform.org/wiki/html/elements/iframe

Comment: Or, even better, use this CSS: `overflow:scroll;`. It is not advisable to use Javascript for things that can be just done in HTML/CSS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use only html/css and it will work fine without javascript 
for this you have to made two section 
first section is fixed in this put that content which you don't want to scroll 
and in second section put those content which you need to scroll it should be like this

```
<style type="text/css">
#first-section {
    height:100px;
    position:fixed;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    right:0;
}
#second-section{
    position:absolute;
    top:100px;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    bottom:0;
    overflow:auto;
}
</style>
<div id="first-section"><!--put fixed content here--></div>
<div id="second-section"><!--put scrollable content here--></div>
```

Comment: Is it works even if the scrollable content is inside the non-scrollable div? in my case it's one in one.

Comment: actually i didn't get it what you need please tell me clearly

Comment: I'm building an mobile app with `HTML`, because of the full scroll all over the screen I have some design problem in some devices. What I trying to get is list in the middle of `div`-page.The `list` is building dynamically but it should be `scrollable` only in middle, now when I use `iScroll framework` and implement it on the list, the list scroll's to the header of the page and out of the middle borders.

Answer (score 0):

Using CSS you can achieve the same result: (300 px of height is just an example, make the div as tall as you like/need):

```
.rtrt{
height: 300px;
overflow: scroll
}
```